# Is there a way to use Font Awesome icons in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I often design UIs in Google Docs (b/c it's really easy to share and let people comment).

I can't find a list of **image** (.png, etc.) versions of Font Awesome icons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [download them from flaticon.com as .png files](http://www.flaticon.com/packs/font-awesome).

Answer (score 37):

I broke down and made Font Awesome vectors in Google Draw, here you go:

https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=1S_wrhxJ-8f9nlz1EZx75Ldl_EM60RdGEVSpi5CFEqTE&mode=public

Comment: I can't figure out how to use them. I try to copy the icons I need but it paste white space.

Comment: How to use these icons in the document?

Comment: When I paste these icons, I only see whitespace.

Comment: insert > drawing > new > paste there

Answer (score 2):

Here's a write up of how to use them in Google Slides, should apply to Google Docs as well. http://phdesign.com.au/general/adding-font-awesome-icons-to-google-slides/

Basically you need to find an SVG (or vector graphics version) of the icon, convert it to WMF (e.g. using CloudConvert) then you can open it in Google Drive and copy and paste it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an updated add-on for Google Slides, it's called [Insert icons for Slides](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/insert_icons_for_slides/96201000411) by Romain Vialard

see https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/insert_icons_for_slides/96201000411

Answer (score 1):

For Google Sheets it is not possible to add icons directly into the text, but you can add HTML entities and symbols. Just copy and paste from here: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score -1):

there is a fantastic add-ons now, search for awesome, it is named "insert icons for doc". see https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insert-icons-for-docs/ihdckhgffclpplbgdlhmbdhmjmlhpbnd?hl=en